# Improper Riemann and Lebesgue Integrals

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

My professor asked me to prove this as a part of a homework assignment so here is my attempt (and statement of the problem).
Let $f:(a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, $f\ge 0$, $f \in \mathcal{R}[a+\epsilon, b]$ for all $\epsilon>0$. Then 
$$\int_a^b f(x)=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{a+\epsilon}^b f <\infty$$ 
if and only if $f\in L^1[a,b]$ and 
$$\int_{[a,b]}f dm = \int_a^b f$$

($\Rightarrow$) Let $\epsilon = \frac{1}{n}$. Then since Riemann integrability implies Lebsgue integrability, we have 
$$\int_{[a+1/n,b]}f=\int_{a+1/n}^b f.$$
Now, consider $f\chi_{a+1/n,b]}$ on $(a,b]$. These two functions are measurable since they belong to $\mathcal{R}(a,b]$ and converge up to $f$ on $(a,b]$. Then by the MCT we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{[a,b]}f&=&\int_{\mathbb{R}} \lim_{n\to \infty} f\chi_{[a+1/n,b]}\\
&=&  \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}} f\chi_{[a+1/n,b]}\\
&=& \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[a+1/n,b]}f\\
&=& \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{a+1/n}^b f\\
&=&\int_a^b f\\
\end{eqnarray*}
($\Leftarrow$) Let $f\in L^1[a,b]$. Now for every $\epsilon_n \to 0$ we will show that $\int_{\epsilon_n}^b f \to I <\infty$, where $I=\int_a^b f$. Note that $f\chi_{[a+\epsilon_n,b]}\to f\chi{(a,b]}$ and $|f\chi_{[a+\epsilon_n,b]}|\leq f\in L^1$. Then by the DCT:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{a+\epsilon_n}^b f &=& \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{[a+\epsilon_n,b]} f \\
&=& \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}} f\chi_{[a+\epsilon_n,b]}\\
&=&\int_{\mathbb{R}} \lim_{n\to \infty} f\chi_{[a+\epsilon_n,b]}\\
&=& \int_{[a,b]} f\\
&=& \int_a^b f
\end{eqnarray*}

Edit: MCT= Monotone Converge Theorem and DCT= Dominating Convergence Theorem.